# supee-11086 for 1.8.x

Tags: supee-11086

There is no patch for supee-11086 for 1.8.x

A few places recommend using 1.7.x patch.

This does not work as there are changes in /lib/Varian/Filter/Template.php between 1.7 => 1.8

1.7: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php

1.8: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php

Has anyone got around this problem yet or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming convention for the new patch has changed for some reason.

So for Magento 1.8 patches you are going to need to apply `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh`

As the version number in the patch name is the newest version it applies to, for example

`PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh` applies to versions `1.6.2.1` to `1.7.0.2`

`PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0_v1.sh` applies to versions `1.7.0.3` to `1.9.1.0`

`PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh` applies to versions `1.9.1.1` to `1.9.2.4`

Answer (score 0):

The latest patch SUPEE-11086 for Magento ver.1.8.1.0 can be done with PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.1.0.

Its works for me.